# Grails 3.0.x - common layout data (menu)

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

image you have in Grails 3.0.x layout with contains some menu. This menu is dynamically filled with values from DB (e.g. menu entries are stored in DB).

How can i on one place retrieve data from DB and send it to layout with each view i gonna render from controller ? (something like before-any-view-render-interceptor)

Thank you very much !

Comment: Maybe afterView method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by interceptor where in after() method i have MODEL